# What is meaning of destroying local variable in function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, pointers, scope

What is the meaning of destroying local variable:

```
void f()
{      
   int x=10;     
}
```

When that function calls, end of function that local variable `x` will be what?

And for:

```
void f2()
{
  int a=100;
  int* b=&a;
}
```

End of `f2()` what will be that local variable `b`'s value? Will `b` pointer be a dangling pointer (will have address but no any value in it)?

Comment: you do not have any `delete`, and since you don't `new`, there is no memory leaks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> when that function calls, end of function that local variable x will
>   be what?

Nonexistent.  Evaportated.  Vapor.  Gone.

`x` here is a variable with automatic lifetime.  "Automatic" refers to the fact that when `x` goes out of scope, it will be destroyed.  (Not exactly *deleted*, as that term implies calling `delete`)

The same is true of all automatic variables, wherether they be integrals, strings, floats, or even pointers:

```
void f2()
{
  int a=100;
  int* b=&a;
}
```

Here both `a` and `b` are automatic variables.  They will both be destroyed at the end of their scope -- the end of `f2()`.  However, all that will be destroyed is the varible itself.  If an automatic variable is a pointer (eg, a *raw* pointer), then the *thing the pointer points to* will **not** be destroyed.  Consider:

```
void f3()
{
  char* p = new char [256];
}
```

`p` here is still an automatic variable, of type pointer-to-char.  The thing `p` points to is not automatic -- that is dynamically allocated (we used `new`).

As written above, `p` will be destroyed but the memory it points to will not.  This is a memory leak.  In order to resolve this, you must `delete` it:

```
void f3()
{
  char* p = new char [256];
  delete [] p;
}
```

Now the memory pointed to by `p` has been correctly destroyed, and the pointer itself (`p`) will be destroyed at the end of its scope since it's an automatic.

The lifetime of `p` and what `p` points to are not connected in any way.  Just because you `delete` `p` doesn't mean that `p` *itself* is now also destroyed.  `p` is still an automatic variable.

An example:

```
void f3()
{
  char* p = new char [256];
  cout << (void*) p << "\n"
  delete [] p;
  // p still exists, it just points to to nothing useable
  cout << (void*) p << "\n"
}
```

After the `delete`, we print the value of `p` to the screen.  If you run this, you'll see that the value of `p` doesn't change from before deleteing it.  `p` itself was unaffected by `delete [] p;`.  But at `f3()`'s closing brace `}`, it will fall out of scope and there be destroyed.

Comment: I dont understand, using delete will delete pointed value, but still there will be pointed address. so after delete[] that pointed address will be deleted becouse of end of scope?

Comment: @VitoCarleone:  Almost.  Let me elaborate a bit further.

Comment: but what if in my question, f() returns that x value, so when i call it end of scope it will be destroyed, so i will get a destroyed value, not 10 ?

Comment: @VitoCarleone:  In that case, you will be returning a copy of `x`, not `x` itself.  The `return` is executed before the function goes out of scope, keep in mind.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40845/discussion-between-vito-carleone-and-john-dibling)

Comment: What in case of JavaScript closure,even though outer function have returned inner function can still have its variable access ,does its variable do not destroy??

Comment: @parshuram,  this question was tagged C++. JavaScript is very different.  You would do well to look for an appropriate answer on SO relating to JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

The variables `x`, `a`, and `b` are all local variables,  so they cease to exist after the function returns. If you try to ask what the value of any of them is, a debugger would probably say something like "Couldn't find `x` in this context."

In more detail, the memory for those variables was allocated from the stack,  and is returned to the stack when the function returned. Calling `f()` essentially placed the value 10 just above the top of the stack; if you then create another `int` on the stack uninitialized, it will probably start with the value 10 (you shouldn't rely on this behavior, since it isn't guaranteed, but it gives you a basic idea of how the stack works on many systems).

Answer (score 0):

1. The local variable is allocated automatically for you on the stack, and is automatically released (hence destroyed) when you exit the scope of the function.
2. `b` won't be a dangling pointer, since you did not allocate any memory on the heap (using `malloc` or `new`, it's merely a pointer to the address of the local variable `a` (that is destroyed when you exit the scope of the function)

Comment: b wont be a dangling pointer, but if that function return type is int* and i return b. now that function returns dangling pointer right?

Answer (score 0):

The pointer itself will also go out of scope. The pointer `f2` gets destroyed at the end of the function, which does in this situation not create a memory leak as the object it's pointing to is on the stack and wasn't created with `new`.

But if you consider the following situation:

```
int *global;

void foo()
{
int a = 10;
global = &a;
}
```

Then the pointer `global` exists after `foo` has finished running, but points to a destroyed out-of-scope variable, the value of which is not defined.

Comment: @VitoCarleone Yes, it is after `foo()` completes.

Answer (score 0):

Once the stack frame for that function is popped…you cannot refer those local variables

Comment: "On the stack frame"  You don't know that.

Comment: What I mean to say is that the C++ Standard makes no mention of stacks, heaps or anything of the sort.  Some systems, like embedded or exotic hardware, might not even have a stack pointer.  Since we're not talking about a specific platform here, you can't say that it's on the stack frame, as there is no stack frame in the C++ language itself.

Comment: Well most c++  compilers make use of stack frame right? Would like to Learn more on this if u can point me to any stack less implementations

Comment: I can't point you to any stackless implementations, as I'm not familiar with any.  What I am familiar with is the Standard which described the laguage itself.  Yes, most compilers on normal hardware make use of a stack frame.  (Actually it's the CPU that uses a stack frame)  But C++ itself does not require the hardware to use a stack frame, or even make any allowances specifically for hardware that does.

Answer (score 0):

When `f()` exits, `x` won't exist anymore. Technically, the memory that was used for it remains, of course, but the compiler/system is free to use that memory space for whatever it pleases. And it will eventually reuse it for something entirely different.

If you take the address of `x` and pass it out of the function, dereferencing that pointer is undefined behaviour of the worst kind. Example:

```
int* f() {
    int a;
    return &a;
}

int main() {
    int* pointer = f();
    //int b = *pointer;    //Undefined behaviour, the compiler could choose to format your harddrive now!
}
```

Comment: " the memory that was used for it remains"  You don't know that.

Comment: @JohnDibling In virtually all cases, it does. You would need to grow your stack massively before calling `f()`, and shrink it back just as dratically in order for the memory to actually be reclaimed by the system. I'm not even sure if there is actually systems out there that _can_ reclaim stack memory at all. Trying to reclaim stack space would be a very bad idea for a system for performance reasons.

Comment: The C++ Standard makes no mention of stacks, heaps, or what happens to the memory after `x` is reclaimed aside from the fact that it is inaccessible.  Since we're not talking about a specific platform here but you are assuming platform specifics, your claim is technically incorrect.

Comment: @JohnDibling My mention of "the memory that was used for it remains" had nothing to do with the language standards, it was simply based on the fact that physical memory cannot evaporate, and that memory mapped into the virtual address space of a process seldomly disappears. That's why I used words like "technically" and "memory"...

Answer (score 0):

You're not destroying anything, your variables go out of scope.

Since its not heap allocated, you wouldn't have any issues with respect to memory management.

If you really want to learn the mechanics of such mechanisms, you can always download ollydbg (assuming windows), and step into right before, during and after the execution of this function, in order to understand how modern programming languages & compilers treat local variables.